# Setting up vps from scratch help with connections (setting up dns on ubuntu)

Tags: vps, connection

I have just installed ubuntu-8.04-x86-default on my vps and am trying to apt-get update but am getting errors to do with resolving urls.

This is happening with every link that I am going to which makes me think dns isn't working.

```
Resolving www.nano-editor.org... failed: Name or service not known.

root@dub:/home/malachi# ping google.com
ping: unknown host google.com
```

How would I go about enabling this? thanks?

**EDIT**

resolved - I used google public dns:

```
vi /etc/resolv.conf
```

and inserted

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hosting company should provide you with name servers you could use. This would probably be beneficial for both of you, as they tend to be much closer to your server's physical location and therefore

a) reply faster than google's name servers and

b) create less traffic on the ISP's connection to the rest of the world.